# How Do Create WebService that Receives XML?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, xsd

I need to build a web service that accepts XML data. (It must accept XML, do not suggest alternative formats as that is not an option.)

I have googled "tutorial xml webservice c#" (and various permutations thereof) and followed several tutorials. I understand how to create a webservice *in general* and have created several basic web services to add numbers, convert temperatures, etc.

Unfortunately all my searches that include the keywords "xml" and "webservice" only turn up tutorials on how to parse XML files *once you have them* or read them from a file. I need to know how to get them in the first place. I cannot find anything that explains how to build a webservice that accepts **XML** as input.

**What is the parameter type I should use for a webservice method that should receive XML? Is it a string? Is it an XmlDocument? Something else?**

**Can someone provide links to tutorial on how to create the C# classes and whatnot *from* the XSD?**

Everything I have found indicates that's it is *usually* done by creating the classes in C# and then using a tool to create the XSD. However, I need to go the opposite direction. Where can I go to learn to do this? I don't care if I have to do it by hand; I'm not looking for a tool to do it for me.

Clearly I am very inexperience with web services, so I appreciate any help you can offer. But please don't direct me to basic "web service tutorials" because I have already done several (I stopped when they started repeating material I'd already done).

Also, please do not tell me "You need to learn about XML, Web Services, Serialization, etc" and other such overly broad hand-waving answers. I am aware that I need to earn about those things, and I am working on it. If you could be more specific, such as "first learn about X classes in c#, then learn about Y" or "learn about X concepts in WSDL, then learn about Y concepts of serialization in C#, etc", that would help.

**If anyone could direct me to any free online courses / tutorial series that go through the process, that would be awesome as well.**

Edit: Ok, apparently this question is not as specific as I think it is, so here is an example.

This is what another agency will send to my web service:

```
<Person>
    <LegalName>
      <FirstName>Ralph</FirstName>
      <LastName>Anderson</LastName>
      <PhoneticFirstName>rah-lf</PhoneticFirstName>
    </LegalName>
    <SSN>122-34-1232</SSN>
    <Demographics>
      <Sex>male</Sex>
      <Height>502</Height>
    </Demographics>
    <DriversLicense>
      <DriversLicenseNumber>1234</DriversLicenseNumber>
      <IssuingState>CA</IssuingState>
    </DriversLicense>
<Person>
```

My understanding is I need to write something like this:

```
public Service () {

    [WebMethod]
    public void CreateRecord(XmlDocument newRecord)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) and [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) are capable of sending and receiving information in XML format. Learn to use those! Otherwise, your question is a little too broad.

Comment: use Web Api , which talks JSON / XML . http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: I am familiar with ASP.NET, that's the environment I am working in. I need to build a web service that other organizations can send XML data to. I literally need to know what the data type I need to use as the parameter on the exposed methods. If I am going about this wrong, a more specific explanation of what I need to focus on would be helpful. As it is "Learn Web API and WCF" is too broad... (I'm already working on that and that's why I am here asking questions.)

Comment: your question is too broad ,it seems you'r a little confuse and don't sure what you want , or you do know but don't know how to express it with words, I suggest to reEdit thread , rewrite it again  with few sentences which explain exactly what you need , without  very long  story .I think Web Api is perfect for your needs. I gave you a link  , start reading , in nutshell , end user sends you a XML/JSON request to your Web Api server, the server maps it to your object automatically( without the need to parse it manually) , and your life is easy . good luck

Comment: Just use `XDocument` or `XElement` as the parameter type, and use WCF, not the ancient ASMX services, or, as suggested, use Web API if that's appropriate.

Comment: look into [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/) (commercial version now, but their v3 is available for free - Google **ServiceStack v3**) It is a good framework for RESTful web services on top of ASP.Net

Comment: Zakos, it's ironic you suggest I don't know how to express it with words. Your reply "in nutshell , end user sends you a XML/JSON request to your Web Api server, the server maps it to your object automatically" missed the point. It is the very first step I was asking. "What is the parameter type?" for the API server. It's a *very* specific question. As it is, someone has told me "its a string" and someone else has told me "use an XmlDocument".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you probably want to take a string as the parameter and parse it once you've received it. There are other ways to accomplish the same thing, but without more information, I can't suggest them.

In order to parse the string once you've received it you can reverse engineer your XSD into C# classes using the `xsd.exe` tool: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The command would look something like `xsd.exe /c your.xsd`.

Then, you would use the XmlSerializer's DeSerialize method to turn the XML string into objects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Colby! That's what I needed to know. What other ways are there to accomplish the same thing, and what additional information would you need to determine which to suggest? I'm asking so I can go learn about them.

Comment: @PatrickQ Patrick, you shouldn't ask these really broad end questions, they're not appropriate for Stack Overflow. Go read tutorials and documentation for your chosen platform (Web API or WCF) and then try to implement it. If you run into **specific** problems, then feel free to post about it on SO.

Comment: XSD ? parse it ? DeSerialize it? why use old fashion way  and work EXTRA hard ... read my comment in above .... Web Api do it automatically for you

Comment: There are a few options. If you are using Web API, you could expose the class directly as the parameter (the outer-most class generated by the xsd command). The web api uses the exact same XmlSerializer under the covers (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization). You could expose the parameter as XDocument or XElement as @john-saunders suggested. Then you could traverse the XML DOM in code or Deserialize, your choice. But, those options assume a specific technology being used to expose the service. You don't specify, so neither did I.